# Laravel polymorphic relations and many ifs

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, polymorphism

I'm still learning Laravel, and I still have one thing I'm stuck on. In my `transactions` table in my database, I have two fields for a polymorphic relation:

```
paymentable_id
paymentable_type
```

So I can add a `Payment Plan` or a `Savings Plan` or any other model, to a transaction.

The way I am doing this is, by having a couple of radio buttons in my view, to select which model has to be added. After making a selection, a dropdown appears to select which one has to be added, and this will submit a `Payment Plan ID` for example.

In my controller, I am then checking which has been submitted, and then attaching that one to my transaction:

```
if ($request['plan_id'])
{
    $plan = Plan::find($request['plan_id']);

    $plan->transactions()->save($transaction);
}

if ($request['saving_id'])
{
    $saving = Saving::find($request['saving_id']);

    $saving->transactions()->save($transaction);
}

// And a couple more, for Fixed Payments, Subscriptions, Budgets, and so on.
```

And this is where I am stuck, I do not know the proper way to accomplish this, or even if polymorphic is the way to go for this (I'm pretty sure that it is though). Having like 5+ `if's` in my controller, or anywhere else for that matter, seems wrong to me.

Comment: Are you using plain html for your form or is javascript involved?

Comment: No javascript / ajax involved, just plain HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution, though might not be practicable, is to change your form to pass two values: `'plan_type'`, `'plan_id'`. Then in your controller, you check which plan type is requested and defer to its model'

```
$planType = "App\\" . $request['plan_type'];

$plan = $planType::find($request['plan_id']);

$plan->transactions()->save($transaction);
```

Of course, you need to validate the data, and check that the type submitted exists.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this while writing my question since I have similar solutions for other things. But I thought I'd leave it up and see what others think, and this is indeed one of the simpler ways to handle this, so thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. This is a simple solution. But it depends on your app requirements. For example, if you want to treat the plans differently, this won't work. Let's say for Subscriptions you need to take the start and end dates. This will will lead back to many ifs. 
A solution come to mind is using a factory, where you pass the request and there you process the data depending on the requested plan type.